# Load phtml file of category

Tags: magento

Hi I created a new theme and created a .phtml for category view.

/myTheme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

I also set the category on Magento Back-end **Manage Products** to use this theme.

However on my category page. It is still blank.

I would appreciate any help on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you updated `catalog.xml` file with this new path?

Answer (score 0):

You will set your theme for your category in Manage Category not Manage Product

To change Product View design you need to modify catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: I have selected my theme on category now. and created view.phtml still not showing. when I select my theme but If I choose base; It shows. How would I edit catalog.xml

Comment: and in your view.phtml write echo die statement in the beginning to check if file is getting executed or not